# Is there any way to send notifications from TodayExtension to the main app in iOS with Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, notifications

I'm trying to notify the main app from TodayExtension in order to update the views with the edited information of the model in CoreData but I'cant.

I'm sending this from the TodayExtension:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"syncUpdate"
                                                        object:thisTask];
```

And I'm subscribing from the ViewController of my main app with this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(syncUpdate) name:@"syncUpdate" object:nil];
```

`syncUpdate` is my function to control the reload of the view.

I have put a breakpoint inside this method but it never is called.

Comment: On iOS, notifications are strictly within the same app.  You have to use one of the published shared-storage mechanisms to share data.  If the main app is running, it can poll for changes.

Comment: @Avi do you mean NSUserDefaults for example? Or are there more?

Comment: That's one of the methods.  You can find others in the documentation, but the last time I played with it, user defaults was the most reliable.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of communicating with the app should be as specified in the apple documentation using **openURL**.

> A Today widget (and no other app extension type) can ask the system to open its containing app by calling the openURL:completionHandler: method of
>   the NSExtensionContext class.

[image]

I Think that the apple documentation may shed light on your question, and provide more information about how to approach the problem.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html

You can also check this tutorial for more practical info.

http://www.appcoda.com/app-extension-programming-today/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11086756)

Comment: Ty for the feedback, I rewrote the answer with more info about the problem.